# This version of the application is not configured for billing though Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchases

Я успешно протестировал in-app платежи в альфа-версии, затем опубликовал приложение как рабочую версию, теперь при нажатии кнопки оплаты появляется сообщение:

> This version of the application is not configured for billing though Google Play. Check the help center for more information.

С чем это может быть связано? Возможно с самоподписанным сертификатом?

Comment: Уточните-вы из маркета качаете релизный версию и она именно не работает? На всех ли акках так? Пробовали не девелоперская акк и не тестовый?

Comment: Качаю из маркета. Не работает на разных аккаунтах. apk создавался во Flash с одним и тем же сертификатом в debug и в "выпуск для устройства".

Comment: @ВладимирМихайлов, и вы релизную версию сделали через консоль? Т.е. пошли в управление релизом - альфа-версия - сделать рабочей? Или собрали новый `Apk` файл и выложили его как релизную версию?

Comment: Второе: собрал новый чтобы увеличить номер версии, и загрузил в раздел рабочей версии, в связи с тем, что сделать альфа-версию в рабочую не получалось - появлялось сообщение что нет проекта приложения.

Comment: Как теперь можно с рабочей перейти опять на тестовую версию?

Comment: @ВладимирМихайлов, возможно у вас файл как-то не так собрался. Проверьте, что в манифесте разрешение есть. Ну и попробуйте ещё раз выложить. Скорее всего как-то не так собралось.

Comment: я добавил свежую версию в альфу и делая рабочей версией получаю сообщение-ошибку "Чтобы повысить уровень этой версии до рабочей, убедитесь, что у вас нет проекта рабочей версии.". Следовательно нужно удалить рабочую версию.

Comment: @ВладимирМихайлов, не факт. Возможно имеется в виду то, что у вас есть незаконченный (не опубликованный) проект рабочей версии. Если так - то его можно удалить (ничего в самом маркете при этом не удалится, т.к. ничего не было опубликовано). Либо имеется в виду то, что текущая альфа имеет ту же версию, что и рабочая или меньше. В этом случае надо обновить альфу файлом с версией большей чем версия рабочей. Тогда можно будет сделать альфу рабочей - она заменит оную.

Comment: я уже увеличил номер версии добавив в альфу. опять это сообщение появляется. а как можно удалить рабочую?

Comment: @ВладимирМихайлов, зайдите в управление релизом - рабочая версия. Если у вас откроется незаконченный проект оной, то будет там где-то кнопка удалить проект. Если такой нет... То, видимо, что-то где-то глючит. Возможно консоль не может обработать собранный флэшом файл. Тогда хз чё делать(

Comment: получилось сделать из альфы рабочую: "рабочая версия -> изменить версию -> удалить". пропадает у рабочей версии квадратная область "не все версии были внедрены". после этого "управление альфа-версией - сделать рабочей" делает рабочей. При покупках опять сообщение "Эта версия приложения не работает с платежной службой Google Play". Дополнительную информацию можно найти в Справочном центре".

Comment: @ВладимирМихайлов, т.е. у вас была альфа, там всё работало, вы её сделали рабочей и всё перестало работать? Или вы не проверяли альфу? Может рабочая новая не успела обработаться маркетом, ещё не опубликована и вы с маркета старую, неработающую версию качаете? Проверьте по номеру версии, которую качаете из стора как рабочую. Возможно надо просто подождать пока из маркета можно будет качать обновлённую рабочую версию.

Comment: в альфе проверял работало, сделав рабочей - перестала работать. в маркете обновился номер версии до последнего. установил на телефон последнюю.

Comment: @ВладимирМихайлов, у нет более идей кроме как проверить, что товары в консоли находятся в `active` режиме.

Comment: Может ли это быть связано с тем что я в консоле подключил Google Play App Signing, при этом используя свой старый сертификат?

Answer (score 2):

Дело было в не верном биллинговом разрешении: по-умолчанию Flash IDE ставит не верное - "android.permission.BILLING", верное - "com.android.vending.BILLING".